Is it possible to implement Microsoft Copilot into my own React website?
I have little working knowledge of AI chatbots in general and have been trying to research this but I am having trouble. I know it is possible to implement ChatGPT into React/Typescript but I wasn't sure how it works for Microsoft Copilot. Is there an API that can be accesssed?

For now, Copilot does not offer a public API for integration into custom applications like websites.
